# How do I require many sub-namespaces in clojure?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

My namespace currently begins:

```
(ns web.site
  (:require ring.adapter.jetty)

  (:require ring.middleware.reload)
  (:require ring.middleware.stacktrace)
  (:require ring.middleware.params)
  (:require ring.middleware.keyword-params)
  (:require ring.middleware.nested-params)
  (:require ring.middleware.multipart-params)
  (:require ring.middleware.cookies)
  (:require ring.middleware.session)
  (:require ring.middleware.session.cookie)
  (:require ring.middleware.flash)
  (:require ring.middleware.resource)
  (:require ring.middleware.file-info))
```

There is obviously a certain redundancy here. How to remove it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
(:require [ring.middleware reload stacktrace params keyword-params])
```

Comment: Great, thanks. But I still need to do   (:require ring.middleware.session.cookie) as a separate statement? I can live with that I guess.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden yes, AFAIK you can't do it in same statement.